# Child widget not updating parent widget when child parameter changes

Tags: flutter, dart, parent-child

I have a child stateful widget that isn't updating the parent widget when an update to one of the parameters occurs.
The parent widget (`OtherListVIew`) is used to display a list of items on a PaginatedGrid with each item having a checkbox. The problem is that when a user views the page and there are selected items that are retrieved by the `_retrieveItems()` the changes do not reflect since at this point the ui is already rendered on the screen with the original empty list. These retrieved values do not reflect on `OtherListView` (`_selectedItems` is then used to display the checked items).

In this child widget I have the code

```
List<String> _selectedItems= [];

@override
void didChangeDependencies() {
 super.didChangeDependencies();
 WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  _retrieveItems(); // this function retrieves items and reinitializes _selectedItems
 });
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return SomeListView(
   key: _listViewKey,
   selectedItems: _selectedItems,
 );
}
```

`SomeListView` looks as below

```
class SomeListView extends OtherListView {

const SomeListView ({super.key, super.selectedItems});

@override
State<SomeListView > createState() => SomeListViewState();
}

class SomeListViewState extends OtherListViewState<SomeListViewState> {
 // override some method here from OtherListView for customization purposes

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return super.build(context);
 }
}
```

`OtherListView` is the parent class that contains the `PaginatedGrid` that renders the passed _selectedItems to the UI. Why is it that after the `_selectedItems` have been refetched they are not reflecting on `OtherListView`? Is this an issue with my state management?

I have attempted using `didUpdateWidget` under `OtherListView` and indeed I can see the new values under the newWidget but they are not rendered on the UI. What I'm I missing?

```
@override
void didUpdateWidget(covariant T oldWidget) {
  super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  if (widget.selectedItems != oldWidget.selectedItems) {
    log.info('OtherListView selected items have been updated.');
  }
}


OtherListView extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String>? selectedItems;

  const OtherListView({Key? key,this.selectedItems})
     : super(key: key);
  
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Why extents OtherListView?

Comment: @bakboem Stateful widget. I've updated the question.

Comment: Uh... Indeed, I don't quite understand what problem you want to solve.

Comment: Let me try to update the question further with more details.

Answer (score 1):

honestly i don't understand your code but the problem you are facing the parameter is not updating because with `setState` it will only rebuild the `parameter/state/variables` that are in the same `screen/class` widget where the `setState` is called  so you have to raise your parameter to the parent screen then pass it to the child with constructor and create a constructor in your child for `function onTap` for example then in the parent screen you use that onTap and called `setState` inside